# Access variables of other components in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an app in Angular using TypeScript:

My `app.component` has a navigation on the top, and then router-outlet of other components

```
<navigation></navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Navigation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navigation',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `{{ HERE SHOULD BE USERNAME }}    <a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a> | <a [routerLink]="['Logout']">Logout</a>`
})
export class NavigationComponent {}
```

Login (loaded inside router-outlet)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login-component',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {

  username ;

  constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
  }
...
}
```

The `login.component` manages the login procedure. After the user is logged in -> I'd like to display its user-name in `Navigation.component`. How could I pass the User-Name to `Navigation.component` from `login.component` ? Or how to access a variable `username` inside `login.component` from `Navigation.component` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make them both use a common service, and store the username in the service.

The login component stores the username in the service:

```
userService.setUser(theUser);
```

The navigation component allows getting the user from the service:

```
getUser() {
    return userService.getUser();
}
```

The view of the navigation component uses

```
{{ getUser() }}
```